# How do get maxspeed values over the length of a motorway?

Tags: coordinates, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have been stuck with a question for quite a while now. I am trying to get `maxspeed` data of the motorway A95 in Germany with coordinates. I am still new to Overpass Api and have tried to access this data with the following code:

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1pO2

```c
[out:csv(maxspeed,
         conditional,
         wet,
         length,
         ::lat,  
         ::lon)]
[timeout:500];
area["ISO3166-2"="DE-BY"]->.a;
way(area.a)["highway"][highway=motorway][ref="A 95"]; 
convert result ::=::,::geom=geom(),length=length();
out geom;
```

I cross checked the coordinates I currently get (I have an existing set of data) and they don't really make sense, I think they represent the middle of the way tagged with a speed limit. Is there a way to extract the coordinates at the beginning/ending of the maxspeed tag?

The goal is to get a csv output listing all speed limits on the motorway with coordinates of their beginning and/or ending. Ideally, I would also want to include data on conditional speed limits.

Thank you very much, I look forward to hearing your opinions!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have knowledge to make same query in for CSV. You may switch to JSON as it show what you expect:

This shows the full way point as it seems, https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1ARl

```
/*
[out:csv(::id,
         ::type,
         ::lat,  
         ::lon,
         maxspeed,
         length,
         conditional,
         wet
         )]
*/
[out:json]
[timeout:500];

area["ISO3166-2"="DE-BY"]->.a;
way(area.a)["highway"][highway=motorway][ref="A 95"]; 

convert result ::=::,::geom=geom(),length=length();

out geom;
```

> ```
> {
>   "version": 0.6,
>   "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.61.5 4133829e",
>   "osm3s": {
>     "timestamp_osm_base": "2023-09-22T10:48:15Z",
>     "timestamp_areas_base": "2023-09-22T07:56:15Z",
>     "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
>   },
>   "elements": [
>
> {
>   "type": "result",
>   "id": 1,
>   "geometry": {
>     "type": "LineString",
>     "coordinates": [
>       [11.1755223, 47.5882506],
>       [11.1756102, 47.5884294]
>     ]
>   },
>   "tags": {
>     "bdouble": "yes",
>     "bridge": "yes",
>     "change:lanes": "no|no",
>     "highway": "motorway",
>     "int_ref": "E 533",
>     "lanes": "2",
>     "layer": "1",
>     "maxspeed": "80",
>     "oneway": "no",
>     "overtaking": "no",
>     "ref": "A 95",
>     "surface": "asphalt",
>     "length": "20.930"
>   }
> },
>
> ...
>
> {
>   "type": "result",
>   "id": 4,
>   "geometry": {
>     "type": "LineString",
>     "coordinates": [
>       [11.1748652, 47.5993618],
>       [11.1748266, 47.5986718],
>       [11.1748149, 47.5982501],
>       [11.1748191, 47.5976261],
>       [11.1748875, 47.5967597],
>       [11.1749877, 47.5959628],
>       [11.1753096, 47.5941843],
>       [11.1753315, 47.5940752],
>       [11.1753840, 47.5937727]
>     ]
>   },
>   "tags": {
>     "bdouble": "yes",
>     "highway": "motorway",
>     "int_ref": "E 533",
>     "lanes": "2",
>     "maxspeed": "80",
>     "oneway": "yes",
>     "ref": "A 95",
>     "surface": "asphalt",
>     "tmc": "DE:12907/12908",
>     "length": "623.335"
>   }
> },
>
> ...
> ```